# xbuf_repl is not replacing all occurences

Tags: api, servlets, g-wan

As g-wan documented, xbuf_repl is replacing all occurrences. But my installed g-wan, running the following code, only replaced the first occurrence of the matched.

```
#include "gwan.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);

    char str[ ] = "kjfdkkkkfldjfjfldkjdkkklfjworhg8kkkugpugulrghkkkr8g";
    xbuf_ncat(reply, str, sizeof(str)-1);
    xbuf_repl(reply, "kkk", "((()))");

    return 200;
}
```

output is : kjfd((()))kfldjfjfldkjdkkklfjworhg8kkkugpugulrghkkkr8g

What's wrong of my code? How to work around it?

Comment: What version of G-WAN are you using?

Comment: what i meant the "document" is in xbuffer.h, line 85:
`// replace all occurences of the 'old' string by the 'new' string in the buffer.`              
`char *xbuf_repl (xbuf_t *ctx, char *old, char *newstr); ` 

sorry, for i have not read the document in the official website.   
Pls update the line in xbuffer.h accordingly.

Comment: Ah! That explains why you were expecting it to replace all occurrences. Sadly, If I correct the comment in xbuffer.h, it won't help anyone else. I am a user, just like you, and this isn't open source.  :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [G-WAN API documentation](http://gwan.com/api) . . .

```
// replace the first occurence of the 'old' string by the 'new' string in the buffer
char *xbuf_repl    (xbuf_t *ctx, char *old, char *new);
```

G-WAN also has this API, which (as I just learned from Gil's answer) also only replaces the first occurrence but within a range of the buffer rather than first occurrence from the beginning of the buffer . . . .

```
// same as above but using a range in the buffer
char *xbuf_replfrto(xbuf_t *ctx, char *beg, char *end, char *old, char *new);
```

Gil's answer shows how you can make use of this to replace ALL occurrences within the buffer.

Ken

Answer (score 0):

In the [entity.c](http://www.gwan.ch/source/entity.c) G-WAN example, you can see:

```
  // escape '<' because it cuts the text
  while(xbuf_replfrto(reply, pos, reply->ptr + reply->len - 13, "<", "&lt;"));
```

This `while()` makes it obvious that one instance is replaced at a time, which is confirmed by the G-WAN [documentation](http://www.gwan.ch/api#xbuffers):

```
// replace the first occurence of the 'old' string by the 'new' string in the buffer
char *xbuf_repl    (xbuf_t *ctx, char *old, char *new);
```

Comment: Hi Gil.  It looks like I guessed wrong about xbuf_replfrto(...).  Doh!  I'll update my answer (and upvote yours).

Comment: what i meant the "document" is in xbuffer.h, line 85:  
// replace all occurences of the 'old' string by the 'new' string in the buffer
char *xbuf_repl    (xbuf_t *ctx, char *old, char *newstr);

sorry, for i have not read the document in the official website. Pls update the line in xbuffer.h accordingly.

Comment: Done in the codebase; will be published with the next release. Note that the Web site documented it 'correctly': http://www.gwan.ch/api states "replace the first occurence of the 'old' string by the 'new' string in the buffer".

Comment: Like many other users, including myself, he didn´t look at the website but he looked at the .h file comments.